# Crashlytics 2.1.9 upgrade prevents app from launching

Tags: ios, xcode5, crashlytics

Run error coincided with auto Crashlytics upgrade to 2.1.9 - sure enough, a few files under Crashlytics have changed. Here is the run error:

```
2014-05-08 11:41:25.561 run[23364:507] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.8
2014-05-08 11:41:25.566 run[23364:507] 

Crashlytics: Configuration Issue

Crashlytics API key not valid. Your Crashlytics run script build phase should contain your API key:
./Crashlytics.framework/run your_api_key_here

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Crashlytics support reached out - it is because the API key was wrong - i'll update steps for how to validate/access the API key etc. once they provide them

Comment: Not relevant then, but in the past I've had Crashlytics update its app to one that refuses to launch. This has then gone unnoticed but had the net effect that dsyms aren't submitted and therefore that crashes aren't collated. Trashing the .app and redownloading fixed that. This doesn't help you at all but it might help somebody else with a different problem who finds this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @Crashlytics over email:

> We added a check to make sure that the API key you had was valid so we don't miss any dSYMs and you don't miss any crashes.

So my API key was inconsistent - probably an error during transition to a different bundle ID earlier in development - also why no crash reports were showing up :)

Comment: Ran into that before. I still don't like the fact that they auto update during your build leaving you unable to control the artifacts of your build yourself.

Comment: Yeah, well intentioned, but scary